# How to create a timer to reload a tableView on a fixed interval?

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer

for a school project we need to create a application which refreshes its content on a fixed interval. The content is in a collectionView. The interval is once every 40 seconds. What would be the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: For a school project, your tutor gives you a task such as this so that you learn to research topics and learn indepenantly. You shouldn't be asking for answers really. your bypassing the thing your supposed to learn

Answer (score 2):

Try the following :

```
 NSTimer *aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:40 target:self selector:@selector(yourMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

---

yourMethod func

```
-(void)yourMethod{

  [self.yourCollectionView reloadData];
}
```

When you don't want to timer, stop the timer using invalidate.

```
[aTimer invalidate];

aTimer = nil;
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below

```
NSTimer *current_timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self  selector:@selector(updateDefaultTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:current_timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

- (void) updateDefaultTimer:(NSTimer *)timer{
   [self.yourCollectionView reloadData];
}
```

`updateDefaultTimer` will call every 10 sec

Answer (score 0):

You can create repeated timer and reload your collection in its function.

```
var timer: NSTimer!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(40.0, target: self, selector: #selector(reloadCollection), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func reloadCollection() {
    // your code here
    // ...
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```